# an arc at what amperage/AC voltage would be at a sufficient temperature to melt most common metals?

Tags: voltage, transformer, electromagnetism, amperage

I have come across a video recently (link below) that uses two microwave transformers to step down voltage from a wall outlet to be used to melt metal as an electric arc furnace. However, he neglected to mention the voltage and amperage of the arc. Since I have interest in recreating this device and do this safely, I am interested to know two things: 1. At what amperage/AC voltage will an arc melt most common metals? And 2. Will a live wire with said amperage/voltage be lethal? I looked through the comments section, and some said it was not dangerous because the voltage was too low to penetrate his skin, however i am not one to put my life in the hands of youtube comments, so I thought asking a more professional crowd might be better. 
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VTzKIs19eZE#

Edit: just to be more specific, to melt 1 kg of steel. Steel has a specific heat capacity of 500 J/kg-k and a melting point of 1643.15 degrees kelvin or 1370 degrees celsius

Comment: you can melt most common metals with a AA battery

Comment: The current needed varies depending on the metal and the thickness of the work pieces and the welding rod.  [That's why arc welders have big ole knob to adjust the current.](https://m.lincolnelectric.com/en-us/equipment/stick-welders/pages/stick-welders.aspx?utm_referrer=direct%2Fnot+provided)

Comment: @JRE say to melt 1 kg of steel

Comment: 1kg of liquid steel is big, hot, needs a suitable crucible, with thermal insulation to the handling points. Once you have that, the arc power that can be achieved by two microwave transformers should be adequate. 40-50v is the upper limit that most authorities round the world consider safe to touch with dry hands, you can sustain an arc with less than that.

Comment: @Neil_UK so touching it would not kill me regardless of the fact that there will be hundreds of amps coursing through it? Also, at what amperage/voltage can an arc be sustained?

Comment: `there will be hundreds of amps coursing through it` ... there are hundreds of amps `available` to a short circuit .... your body has a much higher resistance, so the current would be very limited

Comment: If you're talking about touching an arc ("hundreds of amps coursing through it") then you're going to get badly burned.